# Can i use glcm features to detect dark spot?

Tags: image-processing, glcm

How can I use G.L.C.M. features to locate dark spots in a grayscale image?

If I use a distance greater than one, i.e. I try to to make a matrix for larger distances, will I be able to detect large patches of dark pixels?

Answer (score 0):

You can use features like contrast, energy, homogeneity, Correlation or dissimilarity.

**Python code for these features -**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix, greycoprops
img = cv2.imread("spot.jpg")
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
properties = ['contrast','energy', 'homogeneity','correlation','dissimilarity']
distances = [1, 2, 3]
angles = [0, np.pi/4, np.pi/2, 3*np.pi/4]
glcm = greycomatrix(gray_image, 
                   distances=distances, 
                   angles=angles,
                   symmetric=True,
                   normed=True)
contrast = greycoprops(glcm,properties[0])
energy = greycoprops(glcm,properties[1])
homogeneity = greycoprops(glcm,properties[2])
correlation = greycoprops(glcm,properties[3])
dissimilarity = greycoprops(glcm,properties[4])
#.......................Display.........................
print(contrast)
print(energy)
print(homogeneity)
print(correlation)
print(dissimilarity)
```